# How to access the functions and objects requireJS module

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm working on scripts for a site that uses requireJS and this weird syntax I've never seen before.

```
define("app/models/UserModel", ["backbone", "lang/Lang"], function (e, t) {
    var n = e.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            item: "",
            these: "",
            arent: "",
            important: "en",
            relationship: 0,
            _position: {
                c: 0,
                r: 0
            }
        },
        hasPermission: function (e) {
            return this.get("permission") >= e
        },
        getTotalPoints: function () {
            return this.get("somestuff")
        }
    });
```

I've used require(["app/models/UserModel"]) to load the module and require("app/models/UserModel").default to try and load the object and the same method to try and use the functions but it just comes back saying they don't exist. I've been able to access the functions in another model the same way but with most of the others it doesn't work.

Aside from that I am wondering if var n = e.Model.extend has anything to do with it. I can't understand what the function of that is.

Answer (score 0):

The structure is required for asynchronous module loading to work. A RequireJS module is constructed within a function called by `define`; the function is supposed to [`return` the public interface of the module](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep). In your case, you need something like:

```
define("app/models/UserModel", ["backbone", "lang/Lang"], function (backbone, lang) {
    var MyModel = backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            item: "",
            these: "",
            arent: "",
            important: "en",
            relationship: 0,
            _position: {
                c: 0,
                r: 0
            }
        },
        hasPermission: function (e) {
            return this.get("permission") >= e
        },
        getTotalPoints: function () {
            return this.get("somestuff")
        }
    });

    // return the created model object so that it is
    // accessible as require("app/models/UserModel").default_
    return {
        default_: MyModel
    }
});
```

(Beware that I am not familiar with Backbone, though). Also, I guess that the module you are using was minified and then beautified, because the variable names are 1 letter long, and not very mnemonic? Also, `default` is a keyword, for use within `switch` statements, and is not a valid variable name at all.